# MongoDB Error when querying a capped collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need some help interpreting/resolving this error:

```
OperationFailure: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: errmsg: "CollectionScan died due to position in capped collection being deleted. Last seen record id: RecordId(225404776)"
```

which occurs when I run this command:

```
mongodb_connection["databaseName"]["cappedCollectionName"].find(query)
```

The mongodb instance is a "single" instance, and we are querying a "capped" collection. The query is looking at recent data, which should be in the DB (and not written over via the cap).

Thanks!

Comment: New data have overwritten the next document so the scanner couldn't continue: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/exec/collection_scan.cpp#L78.